# Software Updater: not enough disk space when updating custom kernel (apt works)

Tags: kernel, updates, encryption, update-manager, lvm

I use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with a custom kernel by my hardware manufacturer installed.

When I get a kernel update, I can't use Ubuntu's Software Updater to update, since I get the error "not enough disk space on /boot...". But if I use apt full-upgrade it works perfectly fine.

I have a fully encrypted lvm. My /boot is set to 732MB and /boot/efi to 512MB by default (I didn't change these values during installation).

It's not a big issue since it works with apt in the Terminal. But using the gui would be handy. Is there any way to "fix" this for Software Updater?